# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found Error with laravel curl

Tags: laravel

I have written two laravel apps. **FirstApp** and **CryptoApp** ( name of apps respectively )

In which I send encrypted text to a function called ( Decrypt ) in CryptoApp that is supposed to return decrypted text

In **FirstApp** i am sending a curl POST request with the encrypted text to **CryptoApp**

***cURL post code:*** inside FirstApp

```
private function DecryptApi($data)
{

    $ch = curl_init();                    // initiate curl
    $url = "http://crypto.dev/Decrypt"; // where you want to post data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  // tell curl you want to post something
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "data=".$data); // define what you want to post
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return the output in string format
    $output = curl_exec ($ch); // execute

    curl_close ($ch); // close curl handle

    return $output; // show output

}
```

***The Route :*** `Route::post('/Decrypt','CryptoController@Decrypt');`

***The Function :***

```
public function Decrypt(Request $request)
{
    $crypt =  Crypto::find(1);

    return openssl_decrypt($request['data'],"AES-256-CBC",$crypt->secretKey,0,$crypt->iv);

}
```

**the Error i am getting is  :** "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel_firstapp.crypto' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `crypto` where `crypto`.`id` = 1 limit 1)"

this error has confused me because i know that **FirstApp** does not have a table named 'crypto' but **CryptoApp** does, why is laravel not returning the text i want ?

Comment: do you have some update regarding this issue ?? I think I face the same problem

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have table in your `laravel_firstapp` database. Run migration if any.

also if your table name is not crypto u can use `protected $table = 'your table'` in your model

Comment: the model already has that line added, can you elaborate more on the first part of your answer , what do you mean by , make sure you have table in laravel_firstapp ?

Comment: Check database of your first app, It's not getting the table to append the data.

Comment: @Shwetank this doesn't make sense why do i need the same table on both apps, all am doing is returning text from the CryptoApp

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the `crypto` table already exists in your `CryptoApp`, also  check `.env` file in your `CryptoApp`, maybe it's configured with `FirstApp` database, it should be:

**CryptoApp .env file**

```
...
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=CryptoApp_database
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=****
...
```

Comment: every thing works in order, to give more info, am having this issue only because am using the POST method, somehow the GET method works fine

Comment: This is really confusing, the error that you Get from the CryptApp `'laravel_firstapp.crypto' doesn't exist` tell us that you are trying to access crypto table form laravel_firstapp database ? I'm guessing that laravel_firstapp database corresponding to the FirstApp ?

Comment: that's the thing i am accessing the crypto table from the CryptoApp ( Decrypt function to be exact ), but also i am calling the Decrypt function externally from the FirstApp, as you can see from the Decrypt function it is returning a mere string text